# How can i Check UI Element is exsiting in ui automation

Tags: validation, user-interface, automation

I am implementing  IUIAutomationElement inteface for automating windows ui element with C++

I got collection of IUIAutomationElement by IUIAutomation::Findall method, 
then while iterating elements , the target applicatio crash, while target application UI component disappear and appear continuously.

I guess that invalid access to interface not exist element  make crash.

How can I verify IUIAutomationElement is pointing alive UI element.?